# Representation of anonymous clients

Tags: attorney-client-privilege

In the United States and Commonwealth countries it is not usually possible to find an attorney that will represent an anonymous client. Most attorneys require signed agreements with a known client before they will begin work. Of course, there may be a very small time attorney that might work for an anonymous client, but that would be an exceptional case I would expect.

Are there other countries where it is more of a standard practice for attorneys to work without requiring a client to reveal their identity?

Comment: "Represent" in what capacity?  And who would be the intermediary for the "anonymous client" if not an attorney who can protect their anonymity under privilege?

Comment: @feetwet The point of the question is not to investigate the hows, whys and wherefores of it, I just want to know if there is a country where it is a commonly available mode of using an attorney.

Comment: Then I would vote to close this as "unclear what you're asking."  What does it mean for an "attorney to work without requiring a client to reveal their identity?"  This sounds more like a riddle than a question about the practice of law.

Answer (score 1):

There is no country where it is common for attorneys to represent clients who are not identified. Many countries would allow this to be done, at least to some extent, but the practical considerations insure that it is never common.

Attorneys generally issue invoices that they need to be able to collect upon if they go unpaid, and otherwise communicate with their clients, often in person, in a manner that makes it convenient for the attorney to know who a client is. Also, attorneys generally are ethically compelled to avoid conflicts of interest and this is not generally possible if the identity of a client is not known.

Civil law system notaries are trained legal professionals who don't need to know the identity of their clients to the same extent because they are normally seen as third-party neutrals rather than advocates for their clients, and they often do work on a pre-paid flat fee basis (often with fees regulated rather than set by individual professionals). Still, even in those cases, it is customary and convenient for the notary to know the name of the client in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: How do you know this? There are a lot of countries. Nothing in your bio suggests you would have any knowledge of legal practices in foreign countries. Have you been to Japan? Estonia? Ecuador? Slovenia? How would you know the slightest thing about how law is practiced in those countries?

Comment: When I was in law school, I took multiple classes in comparative law (I won an award for the best comparative law student in my year), was an editor on an international law journal for a couple of years, and had a couple dozen classmates from civil law countries who were pursuing their L.L.M at my law school whom I spent time with and discussed what it was like to practice of law in their home countries over sangria (the local specialty). I also read half a dozen comparative legal practice in law journals and in the trade press a year. And, almost all legal systems follow a handful of models.

Comment: "half a dozen comparative legal practice [articles]" I've talked with lawyers from Japan, Korea, Germany, the U.K., NZ, Australia, France, Spain, Latin America, Sudan, Finland and Russia. I had a lawyer intern from Mongolia in my office for a couple of months. I've read extensively about practice in China, and wrote papers on law in Canada and Singapore. I've not been in every country in the world, but I know which systems are unusual. The Caymans, Nevis, Luxembourg, Bermuda, Switzerland and Panama, each of which does asset protection, work has some anonymous lawyering but it is still rare.

Comment: I've also handled perhaps 30 international law cases over twenty years, e.g.  a U.S.-Japan tax issue, a French IP distributorship, a German company setting up a US subsidiary, a supply contract with Mexico, a Romanian custody case, a Taiwanese business deal, a Czech probate, a divorce with Canadian assets, estate planning for a Canadian, a Chapter 11 involving Costa Rica, a Tunisian guardianship. I've lived and traveled abroad. I've had family members living in Malaysia, Spain, Costa Rica, Russia, Finland, Hong Kong, S. Korea and pre-division Korea. I'd studied canon and Islamic law practice.

Comment: I've presented a paper on comparative law at an academic conference (involving US v. EU law), I did a lot of comparative politics as an undergraduate, I've had lots of dealing with international students (especially from Russia and India and E/SE Asia) who came to my father for advice on personal problems when he was director of an academic department. I've had multiple family members who lived in Tanzania, set up a private law school there and recounted their experiences. My wife was an international student advisor for a while at a college and I provided behind the scenes counsel for them.